# Techniques for set operation proofs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Techniques for set operation proofs?

Particularly,

Consider e.g.

$$E \cup F = (E \setminus F)\cup(F \setminus E) \cup (E \cap F)$$

I can see this true from Venn diagrams, but I struggle as to how to write it algebraically. So how to approach it and other kinds?

---

[Show that $A \cup B = (A$ \ $B ) \cup (A \cap B) \cup (B$ \ $A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881322/show-that-a-cup-b-a-b-cup-a-cap-b-cup-b-a?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

A way to prove that two sets $A_1,A_2$ are equal is to prove that $A_1 \subseteq A_2$ and $A_2 \subseteq A_1$. This is the definition of sets equality by the way.

Use that here. For example for left to right inclusion, take $x\in E\cup F$. By definition of the union, $x$ belongs to $E$ or to $F$. WLOG, suppose that $x \in E$. Then either $x $ also belongs to $F$, which means that $x \in E\cap F$. If not it belongs to $E \setminus F$.

And so on...

Comment: You think it'd be wrong to approach this kind of problem through some "identities" or "set laws"?

Comment: @mavavilj the approach using "identities" or "set laws" as you put it would have likely just used exactly what it is you are trying to prove... the identity you write is a very common one.